# Scope of local Lua functions

Tags: function, lua, local

I'm a little confused regarding local functions in Lua. Please have a look at the following simplified example:

```
function test()
  local function f()
    print("f")
    g()
  end

  local function g()
    print("g")
  end

  f()
end

test()
```

Upon running this code, I get an error in function `f`, because function `g` is `nil`.

From my understanding, both functions should have been declared once the code reaches the call to function `g`. Since since both functions have not yet reached the end of the block (i.e. they're still within the function `test`), they should still be accessible. This code works fine when declaring the functions as global. So, I'm really not sure why it doesn't work with local functions. The book "Programming in Lua" didn't explain this behaviour either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`local function g() <BODY> end` is equivalent `local g; g=function () <BODY> end`.

In `f`, the name `g` is resolved a global because the `local g` appears after `f` has ended. This is what the error message tells us:

```
attempt to call a nil value (global 'g')
```

Try defining `g` before `f`.

Comment: defining the functions the other way around works, but I still don't understand why. Can you explain it a little further? I don't yet understand why defining the function after it is referenced works only with global functions. In my opinion it should work with both types.

Comment: @Legofan431 - the visibility area of a local variable (or a local function) in Lua starts on the line where the variable is defined and **does not** propagate backward to beginning of outer block (as in other languages).  IMO, Lua approach is much more convenient.  I'm now trying to code in C# and have a lot of "WTF?" about variables' lexical scope in C#.